# How to use fetch inside GET request and render those result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, router

I'm using express router in Node and I'm trying to render a page with some data which I get from fetching from an API. However, I get absolutely no results back and it's not the API fault. I checked in console manually and it returns results as expected.

Here's my code:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const resp = await fetch("https://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1")
        const respData = await resp.json()

        res.render('dashboard', {
            name: req.user.firstName,
            image: req.user.image,
            shows: respData
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.render('dashboard', {
            name: req.user.firstName,
            image: req.user.image
        })
    }

})
```

**EDIT:** Here's the view which is being rendered:

```
<body>
        {{#if shows}}
        {{#each shows}}
        <img src="{{image.original}}" alt="{{name}}" />
        <div class="movie-info">
            <h3>{{name}}</h3>
            <span>{{weight}}</span>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        {{else}}
        <p>No shows available.</p>
        {{/if}}
</body>
```

I've searched online but I can't find an explanation for where the issue lies here. If this is a duplicate, please redirect me to the original. Thanks.

Comment: Please give more info regarding your error or the view where you're unable to see the returned data.

Comment: What do you see when you start the server in your debugger and set a breakpoint at `const respData = await resp.json()`?

Comment: I've added an edit @silencedogood. I get no error whatsoever, it just shows the "No shows available" paragraph.

Comment: `No shows available` probably means an exception was thrown and the response was sent from the `catch` block. Please log `error` or read it in your debugger. You can set a breakpoint in the first line of the `catch` block.

Comment: Incredibly silly mistake from me. fetch API isn't implemented in node. Sorry for wasting your time but thanks for your help. Logging the error gave me all the necessary information. @jabaa

Comment: why don't you use `axios` instead of fetch? fetch is an DOM function, so basically not implemented in nodejs

Comment: use node-fetch module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: This is an example of why EVERY `catch` block you have in your server should ALWAYS log the error with `console.log(error)` or equivalent.  Otherwise, simple programming mistakes get covered up by your `try/catch` and you end up make wrong assumptions about what the problem is.  Every developer makes this mistake in their learning process.  The key here is to learn it completely the first time you do it so that you never do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `fetch` inside node because it's only available in the browser. If you want to make an HTTP request from a node app use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)